# How does the ladder excitation of electrons lead to transparency (EIT)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics, laser, quantum-optics

I'm trying to understand the ladder transition in the Electronically Induced Transparency (EIT) process.

I know that to eliminate the effect of a medium on a propagating beam, the electrons must be stopped from moving at the frequencies of the applied fields so that they don't contribute to the dielectric constant.
To do so, at each applied frequency, the electron is driven by two sinusoidal forces of opposite phases. [1]

**How is the dielectric constant, which represents the polarisability of a material, related to the transparency of a material?**

I understand that at a ladder transition, the probe radiation takes the ground state, $| 1 \rangle$, electrons to an excited state, $| 2\rangle $, and the coupling beam must further excite these electrons to a state $|3\rangle$.

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgmE7hDNWe8&t=111s&ab_channel=JoeHope) on "*Dressed States*" it is said that the last state, $|3\rangle$, stops being a good eigenstate, and states this as the reason for the material's transparency.

**How does exciting electrons to a level $|3\rangle$ lead to this eigenstate "not being good"? How does this cause transparency?**

> [1] - Electromagnetically Induced Transparency. Stephen E. Harris. [*Physics Today* **50, 7, 36** (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.881806), [Physics Today eprint](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.881806?journalCode=pto).

This question arose from reading:

> Coherent Optical Detection of Highly Excited Rydberg States Using Electromagnetically Induced Transparency. A. K. Mohapatra, T. R. Jackson and C. S. Adams. [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **98**, 113003 (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.113003), [U Durham eprint](https://dro.dur.ac.uk/4217/).